Search Rate, Search Latency, Indexing Rate, Indexing Latency like in Kibana
I configured elastic_exporter to get elastic metrics in prometheus.
How to calculate and display the following indicators in grafana using prometheus metrics (see photo)?
Screenshot
I have already tried many instructions and metrics, the values ​​are far from reality (which are shown by kibana).
Can anyone suggest which metrics of prometheus i can use to calculate indexing rate, indexing latency, search rate and search latency for many indexes and nodes like in kibana? Thanks in advance

Not prometheus specific, but basically,

a rate metric is computed as: the number of operations / time taken to do those operations
a latency metric is computed as: the time taken to perform operations / number of operations during that time

Taking search as an example, you need to query the index stats (GET index/_stats/search) and take two subsequent values of query_time_in_millis and query_total (e.g. 10 seconds apart).
Then you subtract the T2 value from the T1 value for both metrics and you get their derivatives for that 10 seconds interval, i.e.

delta_ops = query_total(t2) - query_total(t1)
delta_time = query_time_in_millis(t2) - query_time_in_millis(t1)

Then:

the search rate is delta_ops / delta_time
the search latency is delta_time / delta_ops

You can look at how Stack Monitoring computes those metrics:

Search rate
Search latency


Thank you very much for the detailed answer. Please tell me if I have more than 1000 indexes, do I need to request for each index (GET index/_stats/search), calculate the search rate and search latency, then sum it up and then the values ​​will be like in Kibana? Or if I understood correctly from the code, then I need to take the maximum value?

Well it depends what you're trying to show. If you want to show index-level rates/latencies, then you need to query all index stats. if you only want to show cluster-level, then you can get away with node stats instead
